# How to pass a list as build parameter to a YAML template in Azure DevOps Server 2019 (on-prem)?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

For example, consider the following template (named xyz.yml, for example):

```
parameters:
  projects: ['p1', 'p2', 'p3']

steps:
- ${{ each project in parameters.projects }}:
  - task: VSBuild@1
    displayName: Build ${{ project }}
    inputs:
      solution: ${{ project }}.sln
      ...
```

Now, suppose I have the following azure-pipelines.yml file:

```
...
steps:
  ...
  - template: xyz.yml
    parameters:
      projects: ???
...
```

How can I feed the `projects` template parameter from a build variable? Suppose at the time of the build I want to request building just **p1** and **p3**. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use stepList type parameter and pass the same parameter value to template.

For example:

main.yaml:

```
parameters:
  - name: mySteplist
    type: stepList
    default:
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo Write your commands here
          
          echo Hello world1
    - task: CmdLine@2
      inputs:
        script: |
          echo Write your commands here
          
          echo Hello world2

trigger:
  - none

steps:
  - template: stepstem.yml
    parameters: 
      buildSteps:
      - ${{ parameters.mySteplist }}
    
  # - template: stepstem.yml
  #   parameters:
  #     buildSteps:  
  #     - bash: echo Test #Passes
  #       displayName: succeed
  #     - bash: echo "Test"
  #       displayName: succeed
  # - ${{ parameters.mySteplist }}
  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: |
        echo Write your commands here
        
        echo Hello world3
```

stepstem.yaml:

```
parameters:
- name: buildSteps # the name of the parameter is buildSteps
  type: stepList # data type is StepList
  default: []

steps:
  - ${{ parameters.buildSteps }}
  - task: CmdLine@2
    inputs:
      script: |
        echo Write your commands here
        
        echo Hello world tem
  - script: echo "hello"
```

So, you could use VSBuild@1 tasks as default parameter value and could change it when queue build.

Comment: This does not work in Azure DevOps Server 2019. 2020 RC1 is out, so maybe I will be able to use it once we migrate to it. But for now it is irrelevant.

Comment: @mark I am afraid you must do it in DevOps server 2020.

Comment: That is my sentiment too.

Comment: But I still do not see how your suggestion helps propagate a list from a build parameter

Comment: @mark For the sample code, it uses stepList as build parameter and pass it to the template. There isn't a string List type. Feel free to let me know if I misunderstand you.

Comment: Build parameter may be set at the build queue time. Are you saying that in Azure DevOps 2020 I can pass there a list and let it propagate as a list to the YAML template?

Comment: @mark Yes, this is the document for DevOps 2020 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops-2020

Comment: Thank you, I will review it when we migrate.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following example:

```
#xyz.yml

parameters:
  projects: []

steps:
- ${{ each project in parameters.projects }}:
  - task: VSBuild@1
    displayName: Build ${{ project }}
    inputs:
      solution: ${{ project }}.sln
      ...
      ...

#azure-pipelines.yml

 steps:
 - template: xyz.yml
   parameters:
     projects: ["p1", "p3"]
```

Comment: Where do you show how to pass the list from a build variable?

Comment: It's not supported defining an array as a variable, the variable syntax is `variables: { string: string }`.  You can only use parameters to define array currently: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/812728/variables-in-yaml-pipeline-are-not-allowing-to-def.html

Comment: Then this should be the real answer - it is impossible to pass a list from build to YAML. Which is a major bummer. Azure DevOps could have the `split` function, just like it has the `join` function. This way a string could have been converted to list. This is a real bummer.

Comment: The product team in [the case](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/812728/variables-in-yaml-pipeline-are-not-allowing-to-def.html) mentioned "We are preparing to release a feature in the near future to allow you to pass more complex structures. Stay tuned!". Also, you can submit a new suggestion at website https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=22.

Comment: We are using on-prem AzD. New feature propagate to us veeeeeeeeeeeery slowly :-(

Comment: I understand you...currently, we can use `parameters` as a workaround...

Comment: What workaround? I want to specify in a build variable the list of solutions to build and pass it to a YAML build template. If there is a workaround that lets me do it - please show it.

Comment: I mean use `parameters` instead of `variables` to to define an array.

Comment: So, it is not a workaround because it does not let me pass a list from a build parameter.

Comment: Then we have to wait for new feature release~~